# Blocking all incoming calls, sms/mms and emails in Android N and O via ADB content command

Tags: android, adb, callblocking

After reading about [Implementing block phone numbers](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/block-numbers#validation), I haven't found option for blocking all incoming traffic, only by particular URI

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://com.android.blockednumber/blocked /
--bind original_number:s:'6501002000'
```

Is there a wildcard for blocking all calls, sms/mms and emails on Android N via ADB content command?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any option for blocking traffic with content command, but found solution for blocking in/out SMS with

```
devicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(componentName, UserManager.DISALLOW_SMS);
```

and outgoing calls with

```
devicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(componentName, UserManager.DISALLOW_OUTGOING_CALLS);
```